# XNA - Surface - Tracking Touch Input

Tags: xna, pixelsense

How do I track a person's finger moving on the surface when using XNA?

I have managed to get all the touch points and record them but I don't know how to check if a person moved their finger or released the press and pressed again somewhere nearby.

I searched for TouchPoint.Id which looked promising but I don't know how it works and documentation is lacking.

I need this in order to handle proper button input (wherein if a person moves their finger out of the button bounds after pressing down on it then that doesn't count as a press).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID will be the same for a given finger until that finger is lifted up. IDs get recycled so you need to look at every input frame to know when a finger was lifted.

There is an "interaction framework" sample in the Surface SDK that implements concepts like input capture and skinnable button/list controls with XNA

Comment: Awesome. I was hoping as much.